# CakePHP 1.1 - How to response in JSON

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing API with PHP cake 1.1. I want to write response as JSON. I found a lot of content for PHP Cake 1.2 or 1.3 but not for 1.1.

Here is my controller code

```
function index() {
   $this->layout = 'ajax';
   $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json');
   $members['id'] = '001100';        
   $this->set(compact('members'));    
}
```

here is view code

`echo json_encode($members);`

My problem is that, response content type is still `Content-Type: text/html`

Is there any way that I do not have to create view for each function and just write `json`.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Adil

Comment: why is upgrading to 2.1 not an option? if you start developing this API, 1.1 is probably the worst version you can possibly use (much improved since then - especially in this area). upgrading would be my recommendation. also it is "cakephp" not "phpcake".

Comment: Actually, My website already developed in cakephp 1.1, upgrading to 2.1 is good option. But it requires a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 1.2, if you set autoRender to false and return a value from the controller action, it will be output directly.  You will probably need to specific a Content-Type.

```
function index() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json'); // or $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('application/json'); if json is not set up with CakePHP 1.1
    $members['id'] = '001100';        
    return json_encode($members);    
}
```

I don't have immediate access to the CakePHP 1.1 code base, so you may need to check the dispatcher.php, in particular, the _invoke() method, to make sure the return of the action is echo'd if the autoRender is set to false.

I'd strongly advise an upgrade to CakePHP 2.1, which includes a JsonView that can be used to provide a json response.

```
function index() {
    $this->view = 'Json';
    $members['id'] = '001100';
    $this->set(compact('members'));        
    $this->set('_serialize', array('members'));    
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, this helps alot by taking away the need for a view.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question 100% but if you are simply trying to output something in JSON string, take a look at this link:

http://techno-geeks.org/2009/08/easy-json-with-cakephp-and-jquery/

Comment: thanks for reply, Let me be specific.
Here is my controller code
function index() {

  $this->layout = 'ajax';
  $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json');

    $members['id'] = '001100';        
  $this->set(compact('members'));    
  }

here is view code
<?php
echo json_encode($members);
?>

My problem is that, response content type is still Content-Type: text/html

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
function index() {
   $this->autoRender = false;
   /**
     * leave this two lines
     *
     * $this->layout = 'ajax';  // leave it
     * $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json'); 
     *
     */

   // your process to get $members
   $members['id'] = '001100';        
   $this->set('members');    
}
```

As your view code is just fine.